# How can I have a user select multiple images from the gallery, and as they are selected have them put into a queue in order?

Tags: java, android, queue

This is the code that opens the gallery when my button is pressed.

```
 public void openGallery(View v){
        if (v.getId() == R.id.GALLERY){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
}
}
```

This code works to open the gallery, but when the user presses the pictures they want, is there a way to place those pictures into a queue int the order the user presses them in?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to place those pictures into a queue int the order the user presses them in?

No. If you want that, do not use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, but instead create your own gallery-style UI where you have complete control over the user interaction.

Or, do not worry about the order from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, but instead have the user put the images in the proper order in your own UI.

Comment: There is seriously no other way to do this....? I just need the user to pick the images in a certain order.

Comment: @eewfewfwf: "There is seriously no other way to do this....?" -- I have no idea why you would expect something like `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to do that. Also, please understand that `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` is a hint, not a command. There is no requirement that the UI actually honor it, particularly on Android 4.4 and older. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is akin to a file-open dialog on other platforms, and few if any of them offer guarantees that the reported files will be in the user-selected order.

Comment: So what is it doing when I select multiple images? as of right now it opens up, and I can select the images, but it does nothing? I can't implement a listener that waits for users to click the image and adds the image into an arraylist or something?

Comment: @eewfewfwf: "as of right now it opens up, and I can select the images, but it does nothing?" -- you should get those images in `onActivityResult()`. You just cannot guarantee that the order that they appear in the result is the order that they were selected in. "I can't implement a listener that waits for users to click the image and adds the image into an arraylist or something?" -- if you create your own UI, sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have added the onActivityResult method in the MainActivity, but where do I call the method? and what do I input for its parameters? should I call it in the method above and make it the very last line?

Comment: @eewfewfwf: "but where do I call the method?" -- you don't. The framework does, after your `startActivityForResult()` call, and after the user has interacted with the UI. This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities), plus most books and courses on Android app development.

Comment: Ok one final thing, sorry for bothering you. But I made an ArrayList called ImageList, and it takes in URI's so I have this code to add the URI to the ArrayList here.                                                                                                       imageList.add(selectedMediaUri); Log.v("Array list Size:", Integer.toString(imageList.size())); I want to log the size of the array when an image is selected so I can see if something is being added to the arraylist.

Comment: @eewfewfwf: Sorry, but I do not know what you mean, and it is unclear what this has to do with this question. I suggest you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can explain in greater detail what your concern is.